# Automatically and/or constantly scrolldown a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project where a text is constantly written on a html page using javascript and a MySQL constantly/regularly updated database.

I would like to automatically scroll down when the texte start to be written out of the windows but I didn't find find a way to do it, could you help me ?

Here is the actual code :

```
<head>

   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>

   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 

        #myTable{ 
           width:"90%";            
           min-width:250px;
           white-space: pre-wrap;
           word-wrap:break-word;
           position:absolute;
           border:solid 0px;
           top:-600px;
           left:320px;
           right:320px;
           bottom:0px;
           font-size:100px;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           text-align:left
                 } 

    </style> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myTable"> <div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var skip = 0;
        function get_data(index) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: ({"skip":skip}),
                success : function(data) { 
                    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
                        skip = skip+1;
                        showText("#myTable", data, 0, 20); 
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { get_data(skip); }, 30000);
                    }
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

        function showText(target, message, index, interval) {   
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            else {
                get_data(skip);
            }
        }

        //var period = 10000; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        get_data(skip);
        //setInterval(page_refresh, period); 
    </script>

</body>
```

And the test page, so you'll see what is about : http://82.223.18.239/writing2.php

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems they did it with a timer, like a scroll down every x seconds. Is it possible to scrolldown when something is written out of screen instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vanilla javascript and scroll after the content is populated.

```
success : function(data) { 
    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
    skip = skip+1;
    showText("#myTable", data, 0, 20); 

    let table = document.querySelector('#myTable');
    table.scrollTop = table.scrollHeight;
}
```

You can probably changed document.body.scrollHeight to your table element if you want.

then make sure for css to give your table a height and overflow: hidden.

Update: I notice late that you were using jquery, this example just sets a watcher and scrolls on content change.

```
$('#myTable').css('overflow', 'hidden').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
});
```

Comment: It seems to be the way to do but it dosn't scroll down when I put it like this. I tried both body and myTable. Maybe I did something wrong ? I updated the page at http://82.223.18.239/writing2.php

Comment: I tried 

var objDiv = document.getElementById("myTable");
window.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

It doesn't work either. I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: i updated my answer, to use scrollTop and scrollHeight, just need a height on the element with overflow: hidden;

Comment: It worked very well by using it into the function "showText" Thank you for this :)


Seeing how it work I might have two more question regarding your code : 

- Do you know if it's possible to smoothen the scrolldown ?
- Do you know if it's to allow the user to scrollup when during the writing or when it's not writing ?

Comment: if you can accept the accept, that would be appreciated :), currently, it's set to continuously scroll down on content change, so the user wouldn't be able to scroll. You would have to prevent it.